# Run-time error 1004 using Range in a For loop - VBA Excel Mac

Tags: macos, excel, vba

Some context :
 - I'm buildng a big table (1000x1000)
 - I want to fill some cases with the value 1
 - I have the row and column of each of this cases in a separate sheet

This is the code I use to fill the table. As you can see I'm using Range in a For loop. It worked before with a smaller dataset. The line that's causing trouble is this one : 
    *Sheets("Feuil1.csv").Cells(rng.Value, rng.Offset(, 1).Value) = "1"*

```
Sub FillEdges()
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1:A53498")
    Sheets("Feuil1.csv").Cells(rng.Value, rng.Offset(, 1).Value) = "1"    
Next rng
End Sub
```

Doing some research I understood that I may want to save, close and re-open the workbook once in a while. I tried that but it appears that VBA doesn't take the "save, close and re-open" code into account. I tried to figure out something with this help page :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684/en-us

Which led me to a Error 91 with this code. The error is on the third line.

```
    Sub FillEdges()
        Dim rng As Range, mybook As Workbook

mybook.SaveAs "Macintosh HD:Users:Nicolas:test.xslm", FileFormat:=53
    For Each rng In Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1:A53498")
    If rng Mod 2500 = 0 Then
                mybook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                Set mybook = Nothing
                Set mybook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Macintosh HD:Users:Nicolas:test.xslm")
            End If
        Sheets("Feuil1.csv").Cells(rng.Value, rng.Offset(, 1).Value) = "1"

    Next rng
    End Sub
```

Do you know how to fix this error 91 ?

So I'm not sure this will totally fix the error 1004 but I think it's the right path. Or maybe you would advise something else... ?

Thanks a lot for your time.
Have a good day.
Nicolas.

Comment: offset(0,1) - youre missing 0. and you have to set mybook like : Set mybook = Application.Workbooks.Add

Comment: Thanks mehow. This is probably going in the right way.
Unfortunately, I don't understand what the Set function is used for here. It opens a new workbook, and I'm not really sure how I'm going to access the sheet "Feuil2" anymore.

It led me to a different error. Run time error : -2147352565 (8002000b).

I'm currently researching on that.

Comment: you have to create a reference for both. for example : Dim worksheet1 as Worksheet, Set worksheet1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet. I think you need to stop your codding and learn VBA basics... sorry, but it seems like you do not have a sufficient level of knowledge about vba and youre trying to do something thats beyond your capabilities.

Comment: Well, this is probably true :D. I'm sure you agree that it's a shame that I can't manage to scale the macro that I had before.
I'm gonna work on that. Talk to you soon ;)

Comment: yes, its not too complicated if you know some basics. Read on about opening, closing, and saving workbooks in excel through vba. this seems like a useful guide http://www.zerrtech.com/content/how-use-excel-vba-open-a-workbook-edit-save-and-close

Comment: Mehow, Thanks a lot for your advice. I took a few hours to cover the basics. I've already had a object oriented programming class so it wasn't really hard. But totally worth it ! I solved my initial problem and a few others. I'm know improving and automating the whole thing :)

Comment: ok, maybe post your solution for the community

Answer (score 0):

This how I ended up doing. Learning more about VBA before coding was the key here! Especially about openning, saving and closing files.

Note that in the end I barely touched the exemple from microsoft website that I cited above.

```
Sub remplir()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range
Dim worksheet1 As Worksheet

Dim iTemp As Integer
Dim oBook As Workbook
Dim iCounter As Long


Set worksheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
iCounter = 1

    ' Open the new full of zeros workbook:

    Application.Workbooks.Open "Macintosh HD:Users:Nicolas:vba:test.xlsm"
    Set oBook = ActiveWorkbook



    'iTemp = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
    'Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    'Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Add
    'Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iTemp

    ' Add a defined name to the workbook
    ' that RefersTo a range:
    oBook.Names.Add Name:="tempRange", _
        RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1"

    ' Save the workbook: (attention extension fausse, mais ça n'empeche rien !)
    oBook.SaveAs "Macintosh HD:Users:Nicolas:vba:test.xslm", FileFormat:=53

    ' Work the sheet in a loop. Eventually,
    ' you get error 1004: Copy Method of
    ' Worksheet class failed.
  For Each rng In worksheet1.Range("A1:A5038")

  If rng.Value > 0 And rng.Row <> 1 Then
  If rng.Value <> rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
  iCounter = iCounter + 1
  End If
  End If

    Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(iCounter, rng.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1) = "1"
    Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(iCounter, 1) = rng.Value
        'Uncomment this code for the workaround:
        'Save, close, and reopen after every 100 iterations:
        If rng Mod 1000 = 0 Then
            oBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Set oBook = Nothing
            '(attention extension fausse, mais ça n'empeche rien !)
            Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Macintosh HD:Users:Nicolas:vba:test.xslm")
        End If

Next rng
```